# QuickBlox IOS session expired renew

Tags: ios, session, quickblox, auto-renewing

This question has multiple facets which regards an application that has a login, along with instant messaging i.e. QBChat. All of these questions kind of relate.

1) When a user logs in, I create a session, login the QBUser in, and log in the QBUSer to QBChat.  Is is common practice, when a user logs out to log out of QBChat, log out of QBUser and destroy the session?

2) Currently, when the application is sent to the background, I log the user out of QBChat, QBUSER and destroy their session and when the user comes back I create a new session and log them back in to everything. I do this to make sure that the users session doesn't expire when while the application is in the background. Is there any other way to automatically renew sessions when the application is in use?

3) Finally, this question relates back to the second one, if I am using the application and the session expires, is there a call back function that will be called if the session expires?  So if I use the application for 2 hours straight, and the session expires is there anyway I can get a indication that it expired and either manually renew it or have it done automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) When a user logs in, I create a session, login the QBUser in, and
>   log in the QBUSer to QBChat. Is is common practice, when a user logs
>   out to log out of QBChat, log out of QBUser and destroy the session?

Yes, it's common pattern.
Two things that you need to know:

- you can create session and login in 1 query http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS#A_couple_of_words_about_Authentication_and_Authorization
- you don't need to do QBUser logout and destroy a session, you can just destroy a session. It's enough.

> 2) Currently, when the application is sent to the background, I log
>   the user out of QBChat, QBUSER and destroy their session and when the
>   user comes back I create a new session and log them back in to
>   everything. I do this to make sure that the users session doesn't
>   expire when while the application is in the background. Is there any
>   other way to automatically renew sessions when the application is in
>   use?
>
> 3) Finally, this question relates back to the second one, if I am
>   using the application and the session expires, is there a call back
>   function that will be called if the session expires? So if I use the
>   application for 2 hours straight, and the session expires is there
>   anyway I can get a indication that it expired and either manually
>   renew it or have it done automatically?

I do only QBChat logout. You don't need to destroy session every time.
You can recreate session if need without destroy it before.
To check session expiration datetime use

```
NSDate *sessionExpiratioDate = [QBBaseModule sharedModule].tokenExpirationDate;
```

Comment: So I have the new SDK 1.8 however I am getting a compiler error, QBBaseModule is undeclared.  To update my SDK I simply removed the previous one and added the new QuickBlox.framework in the BuildPhase / link Binary.  Am I missing something?